# How to assign a column to dataframe as weights for each row and then sample the dataframe according to those weights?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.5

I am trying to implement a weighted random selection in a dataframe. I used the code below to build the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import exp
import random

moves = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4)]


data = {'moves': list(map(lambda i: moves[i] if divmod(i, len(moves))[0] != 1 else moves[divmod(i, len(moves))[1]],
                       [i for i in range(2 * len(moves))])),
    'player': list(map(lambda i: 1 if i >= len(moves) else 2,
                       [i for i in range(2 * len(moves))])),
    'wins': [random.randint(0, 2) for i in range(2 * len(moves))],
    'playout_number': [random.randint(0,1) for i in range(2 * len(moves))]
    }
frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and then I created a list and inserted it as the new column 'weight':

```
total = sum(map(lambda a, b: exp(a/b) if b != 0 else 0, frame['wins'], frame['playout_number']))
weights = list(map(lambda a, b: exp(a/b) / total if b != 0 else 0, frame['wins'], frame['playout_number']))
frame = frame.assign(weight=weights)
```

Now I want to select a random row based on each row's weight in the new column inserted. 
The problem is that I want to use `pandas.DataFrame.sample(weights=weight)`, But I don't know how. I can do that with `numpy.random.choice(weights=weights)`, But I'd prefer keep using pandas library functions.
I appreciate helps in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use parameters `n` or `frac` with `weights` in [`sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html).

Parameter `weights` can be `array`, so is possible use `list`:

```
df = frame.sample(n=1, weights=weights)
```

Or column of `df` (`Series`):

```
#select 1 row - n=1
df = frame.sample(n=1, weights=frame.weight)
print (df)
    moves  player  playout_number  wins    weight
6  (1, 2)       1               1     2  0.258325
```

---

```
#select 20% rows - frac=0.2 
df = frame.sample(frac=0.2, weights=frame.weight)
print (df)
    moves  player  playout_number  wins    weight
5  (2, 4)       2               1     2  0.221747
4  (2, 3)       2               1     1  0.081576
```

Comment: That was a clear and concise answer. I like people being concise. Thank you.

Comment: Glad can help you, nice weekend!